# Clearance and creepage requirements in EU

Tags: clearance, creepage

I'm looking for the clearance and creepage requirements between live voltage (230V) and SELV (Safety Extra Low Voltage) in the EU.

I had a look at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38673/creepage-and-clearance-when-using-relays) and other questions, but I rarely see numbers mentioned, and when I do see them, they often contradict each other. So far I've seen clearance distances of 3mm, 5.5mm and 6mm. For creepage I haven't any numbers at all.

So, what is required?

(PS: can somebody add the selv tag? Thanks)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a diagram that should help: -

[image]

Picture taken from [this](http://www.reo.co.uk/files/safety_7_-_low_voltage_directive.pdf) document.

Please also note that creepage distances might have to be bigger dependent on your pollution category and your material group. See [this](http://www.frontdoor.biz/HowToPCB/HowToPCB-extra/CreepageandClearance.pdf) document for further info.

There is also [this](http://www.creepage.com/) calculator - I have tried it and for 250V AC, the protection distances seem to be right i.e. basic creepage is 2.5mm with 2.5mm for supplementary making a 5mm total for reinforced. Ditto the clearance figures - they add up to 4.0mm for reinforced: -

[image]